# Re-fill area of erased area for canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, globalcompositeoperation

I am trying to fill color in image using below code snippet for filling color on Image of canvas . Its successfully filling color in canvas. Now I am trying to erase filled color on touch of user using this code snippet for erasing color on Image of canvas . Its erasing color & setting transparent area on that touched position. Now I want to refill that area on user touch with colors but its not allowing me to color on that because of transparent pixels. So Is there any way to refill pixels with color Or Is there any other way to erase color from image of canvas ? Any reply will be appreciated.

code snippet for filling color on Image of canvas

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image;
img.onload = draw;
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1alt1303g9zpemd/UFBxY.png";

    function draw(color) {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
    canvas.onclick = function(e){
       var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
       var x = e.clientX-rect.left,
           y = e.clientY-rect.top;

        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x-5,y-5,10,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();

      }
```

code snippet for erasing color on Image of canvas

```
(function() {
    // Creates a new canvas element and appends it as a child
    // to the parent element, and returns the reference to
    // the newly created canvas element


    function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {
        var canvas = {};
        canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
        canvas.node.width = width || 100;
        canvas.node.height = height || 100;
        parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
        return canvas;
    }

    function init(container, width, height, fillColor) {
        var canvas = createCanvas(container, width, height);
        var ctx = canvas.context;
        // define a custom fillCircle method
        ctx.fillCircle = function(x, y, radius, fillColor) {
            this.fillStyle = fillColor;
            this.beginPath();
            this.moveTo(x, y);
            this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            this.fill();
        };
        ctx.clearTo = function(fillColor) {
            ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        };
        ctx.clearTo(fillColor || "#ddd");

        // bind mouse events
        canvas.node.onmousemove = function(e) {
            if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
               return;
            }
            var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
            var radius = 10; // or whatever
            var fillColor = '#ff0000';
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
            ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
        };
        canvas.node.onmousedown = function(e) {
            canvas.isDrawing = true;
        };
        canvas.node.onmouseup = function(e) {
            canvas.isDrawing = false;
        };
    }

    var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
    init(container, 531, 438, '#ddd');

})();
```

Comment: If you want to apply fill, set `globalCompositeOperation='source-over'` which will cause new drawings to be drawn over existing drawings. (`source-over` is the default compositing mode). If you want to "erase", set `globalCompositeOperation='destination-out'` which will cause new drawings to clear existing pixels where the new pixels overlap existing pixels.

Comment: @markE I want to fill color in non-transparent area of Image thats why I have used `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop'` to fill color.To erase it I have used ` ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'` .

Comment: Check out `source-out` compositing which draws new pixels where they don't overlap existing pixels. In your case it might not be ideal assuming the user is in charge of where the new pixels are placed because the new arc may not be placed in the exact same location as the erasing arc. Perhaps your best solution is to keep track of where the user has erased and if they click in that previously erased area you can simply redraw into that known area.

Comment: @markE  I have tried to track user's erased pixels (origin of clearRect(x,y)). But when I try to redraw whole image excluding erased area, erased area overlapping by surrounded points which are not erased by user. so basically I have to store area (covered by eraser rectangle) & area of circle (previously filled color by user) to overcome that issue. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Your use of both rects & arcs is a bit confusing to me, but I've posted an answer showing how to restore and recolor only the portion of the image that's inside the erasing rectangle for you to start with. You might have to tweak the answer a bit since I'm not near the computer I usually use to test my code before posting. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

Warning untested code!

```
// create a clipping region using your erasing rect's x,y,width,height
context.save();
context.beginPath();
context.rect(erasingRectX,erasingRectY,erasingRectWidth,erasingRectHeight);
context.clip();

// redraw the original image.
// the image will be redrawn only into the erasing rects boundary
context.drawImage(yourImage,0,0);

// compositing: new pixels draw only where overlapping existing pixels
context.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';

// fill with your new color
// only the existing (clipped redrawn image) pixels will be colored
context.fillStyle='red';
context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

// undo the clipping region
context.restore();
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern. Its showing red color instead of part of that image.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still confused about what you need as I thought you wanted to  recolor part of the unerased image. If you don't need to re-apply color, then you can skip the source-in compositing and fillRect. You will be left with the original image redrawn inside your erasing rectangle. Cheers!